# IIS 7 Classic ASP session for website, website subdirectory, application inside website

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, session-timeout

**Environment**: Win server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5

**Website**:

MainWebsite

MainWebsite\Subdirectory

MainWebsite\VirtualDirectory

*For MainWebsite* - ASP ->  (Session Properties) -> Time-Out -> 00:04:00

*For MainWebsite\Subdirectory* -> ASP ->  (Session Properties) -> Time-Out -> 00:08:00

*AppPool* -> (Process Model) -> Idle Time-Out (minutes) -> 10 [I set it to 10 minute]

**Requirement**:

I want the MainWebsite to hold the session for 4 minutes.

I want the MainWebsite\Subdirectory to hold the session for 8 minutes.

*The above configuration is kind of a tiny test I am doing, so I could replace the time-out values with 20 mintues or 30 mintues on my real prod environment.*

The issue is, the Session time out setting for the "Mainwebsite\subdirectory" is not effective.
Though it is set to 8 minutes, the session is lost after every 4 minutes, where 4 minutes is the setting of the MainWebsite.

Is this the expected behaviour, then I dont understand why there is an option to configure the ASP Session Timeout on a subdirectory level.

Let me know if you need more information. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: can you show the code that is setting your session timeouts or are you doing it in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is being done in IIS it does make sense how it's working.  Your timing out the whole site including the subdirectories before the subdirectory is timed out.  The reason you can set it is if you want to time out the sub directory before the main level.  I would recommend using asp code to timeout the session.  You can set it in your global.asa so it's done at the global level for each session.

```
<%
Session.Timeout = 40
%>
```

where 40 = the number of minutes.

Reference: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-increase-timeout-values.html

Comment: Thx robert. Just checked this one. I set the subfolder ASP Session state to 4 minutes. And I set the Mainwebsite ASP session state to 8 minutes. According to your explanation, the subfolder should time-out since I am not timing out the Mainwebsite before the subfolder could time out. But this does not work It always times out at the MainWebsite's configuration.

If i use Server.ScriptTimeOut in global.asa, that would affect the entire Mainwebsite correct? including the subfolder. So instead of global.asa I should be setting it at some common file & include it in all pages of the subfolder.

Comment: that is interesting about the IIS settings, I've never done subdirectory timeouts in IIS.  Do you have them setup as a site in IIS? As for doing it in the code your correct you would want to setup in an includes file or something when hitting the initial page in your sub area. I put the global.asa reference for the whole site time out but forgot to mention about the sub directory change.

Comment: :) it is interesting as it is intruguing. I am going to resort to an include file for now - matter of fact i already have a file in place called control.asp that is called in every page of the subdirectory.

I will have to do it today in my production environment before I lose access. Thx for popping in Robert. I have another question open in serverfault, see if you could help  http://serverfault.com/questions/335942/classic-asp-impersonation-windows-authentication-file-access-denied-iis-7

Comment: one thing though, the reference in your answer is a favorite link of mine, I have always been there.

Session.Timeout = 180 (which means 180 minutes).
When I saw that answer, I read it as Session.Timeout and something brought me back and then I find it is the VbScript timeout that you have quoted and not the Session.Timeout.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, I just noticed that.  must have grabbed the wrong line of code, thanks for the edit.