# asp session timeout not working properly

Tags: html, session, asp-classic, default, session-timeout

i want sessions not to disappear after default 20 min so i wrote this code

```
    <% 

Session("userid")=rsGuestbook("UserID")
Session("TitleofTheme")=rsGuestbook("TitleofTheme")
Session("Compare")=rsGuestbook("Compare")
Session("Thecontect")=rsGuestbook("Thecontect")
Session("LastUpdate")=rsGuestbook("LastUpdate")
Session("RequestID")=rsGuestbook("RequestID")

userID=Session("userid")

session.timeout=600 %>
```

in the asp file but somehow it still 20...

```
<% Response.Write(Session.timeout) %>
```

it shows me 600 but correspond to 20

i did read a few answers here but found nun good answer for why exactly and what else is missing in my code
be glad for quick fix and no i don't want to use cookies.

ANSWER : it was the server side fault or better say "recycle pool" just make it longer to clean and the sessions will be hold longer

Comment: I have the same problem... My server's time is 7 minutes and 10 seconds... I know understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

If the site is low traffic your application pool might recycle after 20 minutes. So setting a higher "idle time out (minutes)" in the advanced settings of the associated application pool might help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `session.timeout=600` on each page - what IIS version are you using?

[IIS 7 Classic ASP session for website, website subdirectory, application inside website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499910/iis-7-classic-asp-session-for-website-website-subdirectory-application-inside)

Comment: i wrote the code on a page i get the session from the db as above and go to another asp where i "show" those session to the user as well as i see the session timeout wich says 600(is the place of writing the code is important and why do i have to use on each page?)

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? In IIS in the website settings.. click on home directory.. configuration -- options -> set the session timeout to the amount you want. http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-increase-timeout-values.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IIS.

Goto the IIS Console then goto on `ASP > Session Properties > Timeout`

You'll see the default value of `00:20:00`

You can change that to your liking.

**Note:** This will take affect on all files and sub-directories on the level you apply it on.